# Is it possible to use a form without its being visible to user?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visibility

I'll explain: i have a form that i want to use it from another application.
but the commands are using the buttons on the form which i want it to be invisible to user (which sends messages to another target etc).

Comment: This is made difficult in Windows on purpose, and for good reasons.... Techniques like this can be used for stealing passwords. You can make your form transparent, but it not receive input when it's opacity is less than 0.3.

Comment: I deleted my answer since you'd already tried it.  I suggested a possible workaround, but it wasn't very elegant (and may not have worked).  I think you should take a look at the approach @user871332 recommends in their answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you want to use the code behind of the `Form` without actually showing it. You should try refactoring your code in a separate class which you can use for your purpose.

Comment: i think that will be the best option , but i am looking for a workaround since its a really big project and minimal time, hopefully after finishing this task i will take time to make the project better.

Answer (score 1):

Before call other application, just hide it

```
Private void MakeInvisible()
{
    this.Hide();

    // application call code

}
```

Thank you

Comment: Yeah but again , once you hide it , and you try to call a handler of a button , it doesnt exist as far as the program concern.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to move the Form beyond the visible area of the display. E.g., set its Location to (-1024,0) Unless the user has multiple displays.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using classes if you don't need to have the form invisible.

```
    this.Opacity = 0;
    this.ShowInTaskBar = false;
```